# What to use to seal large gaps in corners where brick ends?

Tags: brick, gap

I have a few weird areas in my (new to me) house where brick and mortar are basically meeting corners or endings, and leaving huge gaps. The first one is a gap between the back of the brick and the board that goes behind siding, and the second one is meeting external garage framing.

I was thinking about using brick mortar as a caulk, but these are large gaps. I don't think caulk or mortar can do the job here without the gaps being taken care of (And besides, can mortar be wood on one side, and brick on the other? If not, what can be? I have a few areas that need seams filled with wood on one side and brick on the other)

The first one is where my brick wall basically ends at the rear door. Behind it is what siding goes into (OSB?) and above it is wood siding.

Picture:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/phzd8ij2l01grkf/20150624_190657.jpg?dl=0

The second area is a bit different. Behind the brick is literally nothing, and it's meeting the right external corner of the Garage:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kgmln7a88r4zpu1/20150610_182033.jpg?dl=0

I did read about 'backer rod' foam in this thread, but I don't know if that's appropriate here or not.

[What is the best product for repairing expanding gaps in a brick wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4726/what-is-the-best-product-for-repairing-expanding-gaps-in-a-brick-wall)

Any thoughts are appreciated.